# Hook in Android Studio after launching an application

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After changing to Android Studio from Eclipse, I noticed that it compiles slower than Eclipse. When it's compiling, I like to browse the web while waiting, but often I got too carried away. I would like to play a sound to notify myself that it is ready.

I'm trying to play a sound using command like `say "it's ready"`. I wonder if there is a place in Android Studio or gradle that I can place my line of code. It's there a place for a hook after it finished compiling and launching the apk? If yes, how to do it?

I tried googling "android studio hook", "android studio run code after launch", etc. But there is no useful result, I'm not sure what keywords to look further.

Comment: Are you on OS X? I get a notification whenever compilation succeeds or fails and AS doesn't have focus.

Comment: Yes, I'm using OS X, ya, a small tick does appear on the Android Studio icon on the dock, but I'm trying to make it beep or make a sound.

Comment: There's a [box you can tick](http://i.imgur.com/dOiHFmF.png) so it'll make a noise. Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question, though it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In later time, there have been created etc plugins. There are a lot of plugins for android studio, and this one should solve your problem:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1243?pr=

It plays different sounds on events like Build Error, Build Success, Build Warning, Exception Thrown and Process Stopped.

For the installation of the plugin, see this stackoverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617737/6296561

Comment: recently I'm having issues with `instant run`, so I use command line to compile, and it goes like `./gradlew assembleDebug --configure-on-demand --daemon && adb -s 12345678 install -r some.apk && say "compile is successfully completed" ; say "done done done done"`, and I will hear "compile is successfully completed, done done done done" for successful compile, and only hear "done done done done" for a fail compile.