# How to: Install Plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, plugins, intellij-idea

I'm looking for installing custom plugin on Android Studio, how can I go about it?

Comment: what do you mean by custom ? you created or from Intellij ?

Comment: example like genymotion

Comment: I have posted answer have look at it  @zIronManBox

Answer (score 248, accepted):

**1)** Launch **Android Studio application**

**2)** Choose **File -> Settings**  (For Mac **Preference** )

**3)** Search for Plugins

[image]

**In Android Studio 3.4.2**

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me where can I find `project settings` as described in step 2?

Comment: File->Project setting for Mac Preference

Comment: How to chose outlined icon from material icon?

Answer (score 28):

1. Launch Android Studio application
2. Choose **Project Settings**
3. Choose **Plugin from disk**, if on disk then choose that location of *.jar, in my case is GenyMotion jar
4. Click on **Apply** and **OK**.
5. Then Android studio will ask for **Restart**.

That's all Folks!
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Press **Ctrl** - **Alt** - **S** (Settings)

Then choose **Plugins**

Answer (score 7):

File-> Settings->Under IDE Settings click on Plugins. Now in right side window Click on Browse repositories and there you can find the plugins. Select which one you want and click on install

Answer (score 7):

As far as installing a custom plugin there is a [good walkthrough](https://github.com/magnetsystems/rest2mobile/wiki/Install-the-plugin-in-Android-Studio) on GitHub for the rest2mobile library that could be used for any plugin.

Basically the steps are as follows:

1. Run Android Studio.
2. From the menu bar, select Android Studio > Preferences.
3. Under IDE Settings, click Plugins and then click Install plugin from disk.
4. Navigate to the folder where you downloaded the plugin and double-click it.
5. Restart Android Studio.

Comment: Click the zip file of the downloaded plugin, after navigating to the folder.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I started using the Mac Pc for android development. When I go to

**Android Studio => File => Other setting => Preference for New Projects..**

I was not able to find **plugin** option in the setting page.

[image]

Later while clicking option on the toolbar, I clicked on "SDK Manager" it prompted the Settings where the Plugin option was visible and I was able to add the plugins from here.

[[image]

After this, it opens the following setting
[image]

[image: On clicking the **Plugin** it will open above tab]

Comment: Thanks, for Android 3.6.2 this is the perfect answer. The above accepted answers is for older versions.

Answer (score 3):

if you are on Linux (Ubuntu)... the go to File-> Settings-> Plugin and select plugin from respective location.

If you are on Mac OS... the go to File-> Preferences-> Plugin and select plugin from respective location.

Answer (score 0):

2019: With Android Studio 3.4.2 started:

1. Click on File -> Settings
2. Find "Plugins" in the left pane of the popup window and click on it
3. Click on the Gear in the upper right
4. Click on "Install Plugin from Disk"
5. Find your plugin from the file browser **or** drag and drop it from another window to go to it in the browse window, then click on it then click "OK"
6. The browse window will close
7. Click "OK" on the setting window
8. Click "Restart" on the popup

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2021** (for Mac Users Only)

Android->Preferences
[image]

Then click on Plugins.

[image]