# Creating a Button looking like a "L"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am currently working on an app where the UI is really important. So, I need to create a Button with a particular shape. I'd like to create one so my UI could look like this :

[image]

I saw several tutorials about creating your own drawables, but here my problem is the particular shape of my input. The "L" form bothers me ..

Any idea ?

I keep looking for a solution, and if I find one I will post it here as an answer.

Comment: I'm sure that it's an image

Comment: yeah I agree with @Aspicas . Thats an image. Use it for ImageButton.

Comment: @Aspicas I changed my message to show you what my UI should look like. I created one interface with ImageButtons but I couldn't reach my expectations. I could only create squares or rectangles. Sorry if my problem isn't really clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an image of the shape you required or you can use 2 views places horizontally to each other. The first view will contain the yellow color as background with rect footstep image and another view with half of the height of first one having yellow background will be on the right of the first view.

P.S : 
You can always use canvas to create your own views.

 ___________
|.....|.B....|B...|
| G.|____|.....|
|.....|........|.....|
|*.....*|.G__|.....|

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll give a look to canvas!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a view like this BUT you can create a rectangle View like an `ImagView` that contains drawable like `L`. All you have to do is use `VectorDrawables`. create an `SVG` Image and then Convert it to a `VectorDrawable` by using Plugins like `SVGVectorDrawable`. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617737/3116336) is how to add plugin to your `AndroidStudio`

After All set the drawable to your Views Background.

Comment: Problem is that I'm not using Android Studio :(

Comment: I think that plugin works for xamarin too, if not, that will help you to do this : http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/