# Android ADB detect emulator as offline

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

When I run my codes, the android ADB detect the emulator as offline, although I have turned on the emulator. I am using AMD processor. I'm running armebiv7 device image.

Here's the error that I get.

> emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
>   emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore > option from your config file is ignored.
>   emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>   emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>   emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error

Thanks!

Comment: try to restart adb,type  "adb kill-server"  and "adb start-server"

Comment: Sorry that I am new to android sdk. Where do I need to type this code? Basically, the I just click run on the top menu then the sdk needs me to choose an image for emulator and I have chosen NExus 5X. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so this is the easiest way for you, try to install plugin call "ADB WIFI"

Comment: I have searched around the internet and I have downloaded the ADBWIFI.jar file. but i do not how to install it into the android sdk. Do you mind share some of the knowledge on how to install the plugin to the android sdk? thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30617737/2772552, plz  see in this

Comment: I already did the adb kill-server and adb start server but i got this error

Comment: Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

Comment: by the way, i have installed adb wifi..and I will try again first

Comment: Hi i have already installed and try running my codes. I got this error popped out. Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

Comment: show your manifest.xml

Comment: is okay already. I simulate them straight away using real android phone and is much efficient. I just need to build the apk file

Comment: Btw. just wondering, what is the use of eclipse since we can code using android sdk?