# AndroidStudio: Cannot find TBX tool for IDE

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Find this problem when I try to upload audio file or some other actions on android studio.
How can I download such tool or activate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate plugins into your android studio software.

Refer this - [How to: Install Plugin in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617408/how-to-install-plugin-in-android-studio)

And here you can find multiple plugins in JetBrains - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio